# Deploy a flask app in using Cloudera Application

Tags: python, flask, cloudera, cdsw

I have been using the following python 3 script in a CDSW session which run just fine as long as the session is not killed.

I am able to click on the top-right grid and select my app

[image]

`hello.py`

```
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Web App with Python Flask!'

app.run(host=os.getenv("CDSW_IP_ADDRESS"), port=int(os.getenv('CDSW_PUBLIC_PORT')))
```

I would like this app to run 24/7, so instead of using a Session or scheduling a job that never ends, I would like to create a CDSW Application so that it doesn't stop.

This is the settings on my application:

[image]

Logs:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Web App with Python Flask!'
app.run(host=os.getenv("CDSW_IP_ADDRESS"), port=int(os.getenv('CDSW_PUBLIC_PORT')))
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I tried to change the port from `CDSW_PUBLIC_PORT` to `CDSW_APP_PORT` but it ends up the same.

Answer (score 0):

As it mentions [here](https://blog.cloudera.com/building-an-interactive-machine-learning-application-with-cml/) maybe you need to change this line of code

```
app.run(host=os.getenv("CDSW_IP_ADDRESS"), port=int(os.getenv('CDSW_PUBLIC_PORT')))
```

to this

```
app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=int(os.environ['CDSW_APP_PORT']))
```

Hope it works!